# How to update state shared between Parent and Child React components within the Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child

I've built a simple interface for selecting items from a menu, contained in a component called `Sodas`, and it's displayed in the Parent component: `VendingMachine`.

As it is, `Sodas` is able to successfully change the state in the `VendingMachine`, however, the state cannot be changed within the `VendingMachine` itself.

The following code represents the `VendingMachine` component:

```
import Sodas from './Sodas';

const VendingMachine = () =>
{
   // Track selected soda
   const [selectedSoda, setSoda] = useState({ sodaName: '', stock: 0 });

   const handleSodaSelection = (soda) => setSoda(soda);

   // Reset the selected soda
   const sellSoda = () => setSoda({ sodaName: '', stock: 0 });

   return (
   <div>
      Soda to Purchase: {selectedSoda.sodaName}
      <Sodas handleSodaSelection={handleSodaSelection} />
      <div onClick={sellSoda}>Buy Selected Soda</div>
   </div
}
```

The following code represents the `Sodas` Component

```
function Sodas({ handleSodaSelection  })
{
   // Tracks soda selected, and returns to Parent component
    const [sodaSelected, setSodaSelected] = useState({ sodaName: '', stock: 0 });
    React.useEffect(() => handleSodaSelection(sodaSelected), [sodaSelected, handleSodaSelection]);

return (
   <div className='soda_container'>
      <div onClick={() => setSodaSelected({ sodaName: 'Cola', stock: 7 })}>Soda</div>
   </div>)
}
```

Specifically, the issue is that `setSoda` does not work within `VendingMachine` and only works when passed to the `Sodas` component. I'm not sure if this can only work as a one way relationship or if there is something I'm missing in the syntax.

Any help or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is that you don't have a shared state. You have two independent states. Keep only a single state in the parent state, and make both the state and the setter available to the child component by passing them as props.